# Is this the proper way to use promises with Sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, promise, sequelize.js

```
var newUser;

newUser = {
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
  username: req.body.username,
  password: req.body.password
};

global.db.User.create(newUser).then(function(dbUser) {
  var newEntity;
  newEntity = {
    name: newUser.name + " Default Entity"
  };
  return global.db.Entity.create(newEntity);
}).then(function(dbEntity) {
  console.log(dbEntity);
  return res.json(dbUser.display());
})["catch"](function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  return next(err);
});
```

`global.db` is a Sequelize object that has a `User` model and `Entity` model. I want to first create a user, then create an entity for that user. Is this the proper way to chain things together to have promises be useful?

Comment: You may also want to read http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-05/introducing-promises

Comment: @SLaks nice article! It has several (minor) mistakes - where do I report them to? Also - since promises have now a rather fixed syntax for creation you might want to use that syntax (promise constructor and not a deferred)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Thanks! I do mention promise constructors, right after deferreds.  Note that it's not only about JS promises.  You can leave comments on the blog post, or even send a pull request (https://github.com/SLaks/SLaks.Blog/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2015-01-05-introducing-promises.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; that is completely correct.

Answer (score 2):

Might be cleaner if you invoke `catch` as `.catch()` instead of `["catch"]`:

```
global.db.User.create(newUser).then(function(dbUser) {
  var newEntity;
  newEntity = {
    name: newUser.name + " Default Entity"
  };
  return global.db.Entity.create(newEntity);
}).then(function(dbEntity) {
  console.log(dbEntity);
  return res.json(dbUser.display());
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
  return next(err);
});
```

Makes everything nice and uniform.

Comment: That's actually a holdover from the `coffee script` conversion =)